# Displaying faces messages bound to elements being iterated by p:dataTable

Tags: primefaces

I have a hierarchical model that is displayed in nested tables for edition:

```
root (root bean)
+- property1 (property of root)
+- children (collection of child beans)
   +- property2 (property of child)
   +- subchildren (collection of subchild beans)
      +- property3 (property of subchild)
```

I am running a custom-made validation on my whole model that is adding `FacesMessages` to the `FacesContext`on the following paths:

- root
- root:property1
- root:children:0
- root:children:0:property2
- root:children:0:subchildren:0
- root:children:0:subchildren:0:property3
- ...
- root:children:4:subchildren:3:property3

`FacesMessages` can be bound at every level (root bean, properties, and beans in collections).

The managed bean `myBean` is holding the root bean of my model which is being edited.

To edit this model, I am using something like this (simplified to the extreme to exhibit the problem I have):

```
<h:form id="root">

    <h:messages for="root">

    <h:inputText value="#{myBean.root.property1}" id="property1" />
    <h:messages for="property1">

    <h:dataTable value="#{myBean.root.children}" var="child" id="children">

        <f:facet name="header">children</f:facet>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">*</f:facet>
            <h:messages for="children" />
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">property2</f:facet>
            <h:inputText value="#{child.property2}" id="property2" />
            <h:messages for="property2">
        </h:column>

        <h:column>
            <f:facet name="header">subchildren</f:facet>
            <h:dataTable value="#{child.subchildren}" var="subchild" id="subchildren">
                ...
            </h:dataTable>
        </h:column>

    </h:dataTable>

</h:form>
```

For simplicity, the first column of the table (*) is used to display validation messages of the current row bean (thus, at the bean level like root:children:0, not on its properties).

When using the standard html taglib (`h:dataTable`), everything is working, I can see validation messages at every level.

But when I try to use a primefaces table (`p:dataTable/p:column/p:messages`) instead of (`h:dataTable/h:column/h:messages`), I can't see validation messages on beans that are in collections:

- root:children:0 (not shown)
- root:children:0:subchildren:0 (not shown)

Messages linked to properties of those beans are well displayed:

- root:children:0:property2 (shown)
- root:children:0:subchildren:0:property3 (shown)

If I rewrite my markup with `ui:repeat` instead of `h:dataTable`, everything works too so I think the problem is in primefaces.

Maybe I am pushing things a bit too far and got everything working with `ui:repeat` and `h:dataTable` by luck but I would like to make it work with primefaces too as I want to use `p:rowExpansion`.

Is there something I can do to make it work or is it a *bug* in primefaces?

Thanks for reading my <del>question</del> *summoning incantation for the BalusC JSF god* up to here! :-)

Comment: Please state PF version? And what if you use `h:messages` with a `p:dataTable`? Does it fail to?

Comment: PF for one reason or another decided to have their repeating components (like `p:dataTable`) not extend the default jsf UIData class, but created their own (since PF 5.0 if I am right). Since then, there are several (to many imo) issues with these components. This might also be one of them (it at least feels related to the other issues). Please file an issue in the PF github with a simple [mcve].

Comment: OK thanks, I will do that.

Comment: See https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/issues/1010